# Many Many-To-Many relationships Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot

I am trying to achieve the following:
I am trying to set up the database for an ecommerce like website and I have a Products table. Each product might have several SpecificationsHeader (which is something like the 'title' for each specificationsgroup), "under" this SpecificationsHeader could be many Specifications (those again act like 'titles', like 'Size'), for each one of those Specifications, a value should be assigned like 'XXL'. The main difficulty i face is getting the relationships correct since i would like to have all of them kinda reusable.

Example Product 1:

**Product**: iPhone

**SpecificationHeader**: 'CPU & RAM'

**Specification**(s): 'CPU speed' - **SpecificationValue**: '1.4GHz'

**Specification**(s): 'Ram size' - **SpecificationValue**: '2GB'

...

**SpecificationHeader**: 'Camera'

**Specification**(s): 'Camera Resolution' - **SpecificationValue**: '12MP'

---

Example Product 2: (might share some of the above values or might have completely different)

**Product**: Samsung

**SpecificationHeader**: 'CPU & RAM'

**Specification**(s): 'CPU speed' - **SpecificationValue**: '3GHz'

**Specification**(s): 'Ram size' - **SpecificationValue**: '4GB'

**Specification**(s): '4G' - **SpecificationValue**: 'Yes'

...

**SpecificationHeader**: 'Networking'

**Specification**(s): 'Something' - **SpecificationValue**: 'somevalue'

---

I experimented with several Pivot tables but i am obviously doing something wrong since the best i managed is getting the headers and specifications but not getting the values.
My latest approach was this:
[image: mysqldiagramm]

But all of you who know what are doing will find it utterly stupid.
So,
**the ideal solution would be**:
Fetching the product brings with it a specification - specificationValue pair, grouped under the specificationheader.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ate the first sight, the naming of your tables makes it hard to understand your  ERD, proper tables names are `attributeGroups` `attributes` `values` `attributeValues` `products` and `productAtrribueValue`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would change only one thing, it's to set `belongsTo` relation between `SpecificationValue` and `Specification`

Like this:
[image]

But it produce some limits like if you have specifications `memory` and `RAM` you wont be able to use the same specification value `8 gb` for each.

And there are some positive moments.
Example: User has added new specification to product `size`. You will show only needed values such as `s`, `m`, `l`, `xl` etc. without values from the other specifications like `3 Gb`, `Plastic`, `4x4`